# How to add correct opacity animation on progress indicator

Tags: flutter, dart

I was searching for a way to make a spinner effect with dots opacities. Are there any way on how to make correct animation?
What I've tried:

1. Add rotation - not correct animation;
2. Add animation value on dot opacity computing;

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DotCircleProgressbarPainter extends CustomPainter {
  DotCircleProgressbarPainter(
      {required this.color,
      required this.strokeWidth,
      required this.animation,
      this.numberOfVisibleCircles = 9,
      this.numberOfCircles = 10})
      : super(repaint: animation);

  final Color color;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final int numberOfCircles;
  final int numberOfVisibleCircles;
  final Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final radius = size.width / 2;

    final dotSpacing = (2 * math.pi) / numberOfCircles;

    for (int pos = 0; pos < numberOfCircles; pos++) {
      final dotOpacity =
          (1.0 - pos / (numberOfVisibleCircles - 1)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);

      final dotPaint = Paint()
        ..color = color.withOpacity(dotOpacity)
        ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

      final double angle = pos * dotSpacing;
      final double x = radius + radius * math.cos(angle + math.pi);
      final double y = radius + radius * math.sin(angle + math.pi);

      canvas.drawCircle(Offset(x, y), strokeWidth / 2, dotPaint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DotCircleProgressbarPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Example image:

[image]

Thanks for help!

Comment: so you want your circles to be static and only theirs opacity is animated?

Comment: Hi @pskink! I want animate only opacities of those circles, not rotation.

Comment: @pskink, please post your code here, I'll mark it as accepted! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have a simple `StatefulWidget` using a `CustomPaint`:

```
class SpinningDots extends StatefulWidget {
  const SpinningDots({
    super.key,
    required this.simulation,
    required this.numDots,
    required this.dotRadius,
    this.dotColor = Colors.black,
  });

  final Simulation simulation;
  final int numDots;
  final double dotRadius;
  final Color dotColor;

  @override
  State<SpinningDots> createState() => _SpinningDotsState();
}

class _SpinningDotsState extends State<SpinningDots> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final controller = AnimationController.unbounded(vsync: this)
    ..animateWith(widget.simulation);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: _SpinningDotsPainter(
        animation: controller,
        numDots: widget.numDots,
        dotRadius: widget.dotRadius,
        dotColor: widget.dotColor,
      ),
      child: const SizedBox.expand(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class _SpinningDotsPainter extends CustomPainter {
  _SpinningDotsPainter({
    required this.animation,
    required this.numDots,
    required this.dotRadius,
    required this.dotColor,
  }) : super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final int numDots;
  final double dotRadius;
  final Color dotColor;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final distance = size.shortestSide / 2 - dotRadius;
    for (int i = 0; i < numDots; i++) {
      final paint = Paint()
        ..color = dotColor.withOpacity((animation.value - i / numDots) % 1);
      final center = size.center(Offset.zero) + Offset.fromDirection(2 * pi * i / numDots, distance);
      canvas.drawCircle(center, dotRadius, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_SpinningDotsPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

and you can use it like this (if you want infinite simulation replace `16` which is `endDistance` in `GravitySimulation` ctor with `double.infinity`:

```
body: Center(
  child: SizedBox.fromSize(
    size: const Size.square(64),
    child: SpinningDots(
      simulation: GravitySimulation(0, 0, 16, 1.5),
      numDots: 8,
      dotColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      dotRadius: 6,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the opacity of the dots based on the current animation value.

Modified `paint()`:

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
 final radius = size.width / 2;
 final dotSpacing = (2 * math.pi) / numberOfCircles;
 final currentAnimationValue = animation.value;

 for (int pos = 0; pos < numberOfCircles; pos++) {
    final dotOpacity = (currentAnimationValue - pos / numberOfCircles).abs().clamp(0.0, 1.0);

    final dotPaint = Paint()
      ..color = color.withOpacity(dotOpacity)
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final double angle = pos * dotSpacing;
    final double x = radius + radius * math.cos(angle + math.pi);
    final double y = radius + radius * math.sin(angle + math.pi);

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(x, y), strokeWidth / 2, dotPaint);
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeap, I've tried that before, but it jumps on animation restarts, don't know why. Moreover I need to connect animation to numberOfVisibleCircles and then I got animation that is not correct. Thanks for help!